# ActiveAdmin uninitialized constant Twilio::REST::CLIENT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, twilio

Most likely a very  basic and simple question. But super happy if someone could help me out (:

I am trying to include Twilio into Activeadmin. I took this code example from the very comprehensive Twilio tutorial.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Sms do
...
controller do 
def create 
 account_sid = "secret"
 auth_token =  "secret"
 client = Twilio::REST::CLIENT.new account_sid, auth_token
 from = "secret"
 client.account.messages.create(
  :from => from,
  :to => @customer[:phone],
  :body => @message[:text]
 )
```

But where can i tell AA to load the Twilio gem, e.g. where do i have to put the  `require twilio-gem` statement? I tried it everywhere in the `Sms.rb` file and i looked into the  `initializers/active_admin.rb` 
but i cannot figure this out. Thanks for any help in advance.

In my rails console everything is working fine and i am able to use this code without problems so its really hanging by the gem inclusion.

Comment: I'm sure there's better than this but did you try putting your twillo gem before your active_admin gem in Gemfile ?

Comment: That was a nice hint, and after checking my Gemfile i saw the AA gem was before the twilio one but after changing the order and restarting the servers i get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist. I was straight wrong with my last answer, so have deleted it.

You are trying to use the `Twilio::REST::CLIENT` but the class is actually called `Twilio::REST::Client` (note, `Client` is not all caps).

The gem is certainly loaded by Rails, but the error is coming from that typo. Update to `Twilio::REST::Client` and everything should start working again.

Comment: I feel incredible awkward right now since i read a post about the same problem maybe 30 minutes ago where the author wrote Rest instead of REST ..... (: and now this ...

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make, there's plenty of times I've done it myself! Good luck with the rest of the app!